# Access Azure AD user from js

Tags: azure-active-directory, auth0

We are implementing SSO with Azure AD for our SPA Angular application. We have successfully implemented SSO referring the documentation. But we have a requirement if the user is already logged in to AD, user need not to be redirected to the login page. User should automatically be redirected to the landing page. How can we implement this with Auth0?

I'm in thought of using a js libray like MSAL. But the issue is that the app is not hosted in Azure. Is there a way to figure out whether there is a active directory instance for a given domain.

Answer (score 0):

If a valid session exists after already logging in with Azure AD you will not be asked to login again if your using MSAL.